# Пакетный менеджер Conan. Как задать транзитивные зависимости?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, conan, cmakelists

Есть библиотека TGUI, которая зависит от SFML. Как в conan файле сообщить ей, что она зависит от SFML?

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools
import os

class TGUI(ConanFile):
    name = "GUI"
    version = "0.10"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    requires = "sfml/2.5.1"
    
    def source(self):
        print("source")
        git = tools.Git(self.source_folder)
        git.clone("https://github.com/texus/TGUI.git")
        
    def build(self):
        print("build")
        cmake = CMake(self)
        self.run('cmake -D TGUI_BACKEND:STRING=SFML_GRAPHICS')
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()
        
    def package(self):
        print("package")
        self.copy("*.h", dst="inc", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.cpp", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        
    def package_info(self):
        print("package_info")
        self.cpp_info.includedirs = ["inc"]
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["TGUI"]
```

Падает с ошибками:

```
-- Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_DIR)
-- Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_DIR)
CMake Error at cmake/Dependencies.cmake:93 (message):
  CMake couldn't find SFML.

  Set SFML_DIR to the directory containing SFMLConfig.cmake (usually
  something like SFML_ROOT/lib/cmake/SFML)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:106 (tgui_find_dependency_sfml)
  src/Backend/CMakeLists.txt:153 (tgui_add_dependency_sfml)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:270 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Ошибся. Не транзитивная, а прямая зависимость!

Answer (score 2):

нужно добавить `generators = "cmake_find_package_multi"` и заменить:
`self.run('cmake -D TGUI_BACKEND:STRING=SFML_GRAPHICS')`
на
`cmake.definitions["TGUI_BACKEND"] = "SFML_GRAPHICS"`

```py
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools
import os

class TGUI(ConanFile):
    name = "GUI"
    version = "0.10"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    requires = "sfml/2.5.1"
    generators = "cmake_find_package_multi"
    
    def source(self):
        print("source")
        git = tools.Git(self.source_folder)
        git.clone("https://github.com/texus/TGUI.git")
        
    def build(self):
        print("build")
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.definitions["TGUI_BACKEND"] = "SFML_GRAPHICS"
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()
        
    def package(self):
        print("package")
        self.copy("*.h", dst="inc", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.cpp", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        
    def package_info(self):
        print("package_info")
        self.cpp_info.includedirs = ["inc"]
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["TGUI"]
```

работает:

```
[ 83%] Built target tgui
[ 95%] Building CXX object gui-builder/CMakeFiles/gui-builder.dir/src/GuiBuilder.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object gui-builder/CMakeFiles/gui-builder.dir/src/Form.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object gui-builder/CMakeFiles/gui-builder.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable gui-builder
[100%] Built target gui-builder
GUI/0.10: Package 'a1a14a21cd8d28b6070be50be5a9f431eb07a3f1' built
GUI/0.10: Build folder /home/conan/.conan/data/GUI/0.10/_/_/build/a1a14a21cd8d28b6070be50be5a9f431eb07a3f1
GUI/0.10: Generated conaninfo.txt
GUI/0.10: Generated conanbuildinfo.txt
GUI/0.10: Generating the package
GUI/0.10: Package folder /home/conan/.conan/data/GUI/0.10/_/_/package/a1a14a21cd8d28b6070be50be5a9f431eb07a3f1
GUI/0.10: Calling package()
package
GUI/0.10 package(): Packaged 4 '.h' files: nanosvgrast.h, gl.h, nanosvg.h, stb_image.h
GUI/0.10 package(): Packaged 178 '.cpp' files
GUI/0.10: Package 'a1a14a21cd8d28b6070be50be5a9f431eb07a3f1' created
GUI/0.10: Created package revision db1549eea2a898e87ce6bda879200c7d
package_info
```